# "women's ideal" vs "ideal woman"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What would be the best way to express the following:

> His [...] is someone who <a list of attributes>

The context is a man uttering the above phrase and describing what a hypothetical ideal woman from his perspective would look like. (of course, it could be with genders swapped, but let's stay with this for the sake of the example)

If I used **"ideal woman"** I feel it seems to refer to an already existing person, but I wanted to express a purely idealistic concept. The word/phrase should not make it feel like referring to an actual person, but to a batch of attributes.

If I directly translate from other languages, I would say **"women's ideal"**, but I'm not sure if that means what I think it means. The possessive makes me unsure. Does it mean what I intend to say, or does the possessive makes it into something belonging to a woman?

Another such translation would be "woman-ideal", but it feels strange and not English-sounding to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Ideal woman" is the term you want. It specifically references a non-existent person and compares it to one who exists.

> She is his ideal woman.

Means that this woman matches up with *his* concept of **the** "ideal woman".

So, it's perfectly appropriate to say something like:

> He spent so much time looking for his *ideal woman* that he missed out on love entirely.
>   His ideal woman is tall, witty, gorgeous, adventuresome, intelligent and considerate.

---

"Women's ideal" or "woman's ideal" is exactly the opposite.  It means what a woman finds ideal in a partner.

> He is the women's ideal [partner] - tall, witty, gorgeous, adventuresome, intelligent and considerate.

You could do "men's ideal" or "man's ideal" in the same way.